# Associations between objects in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an XML file that contains a description of a few entities. Each Entity has its own properties, each property has its own attributes and at the end of the XML file, there are associations between the entities.

I'm working with WPF (**MVVM**) to convert this XML file into a graphical diagram. Each entity is shown as a block and the associations must be displayed as lines that connect the entities (comparable with "edmx" in VS). Until now, I can display all the entities with all the properties using DataTemplates, Styles and ItemsControls. The only problem is that I can't convert the associations into graphical lines.

[image]

I tried to follow this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4) without any progress. Does anyone have any ideas how can I display those associations between my blocks(entities)?

Thank you